# Автоматизированное обновление службы windows на C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

Есть служба windows, написанная на c#. Сейчас при каждом изменении приходится останавливать службу на удаленном сервере, копировать руками все файлы и перезапускать ее, тоже руками. Очень хочется какого-то способа автоматизировать сие действие.

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой способ - взять готовую систему деплоймента, которая умеет обновлять Windows Service, и просто взвалить проблему апдейта сервиса на нее.

Мы используем [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/). Он [умеет деплоить Windows Services из коробки](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/windows-services). Бесплатен до 10 машин.